# Casting(?) a known superclass object to an unknown subclass reference

Tags: java, class, casting, subclass, superclass

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm working on a Java project right now and I'm trying to cast a known superclass to an unknown subclass.

Here's the code:

```
public void getShirtType(Person person) {

    Clothing article; // Clothing is a superclass of different subclasses of Clothing

    for(Clothing clothing : person.getClothing()) { // person.getClothing() returns List<Clothing>

        if(clothing.hasSleeves()) { // hasSleeves() is boolean

            article = ???;
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

This code gets the first instance of an article of Clothing with sleeves and then ends the loop.

I don't know what to put at the location of the question marks. Normally, I could just have something like `article = (SleevedShirt) clothing;`, but there are various different subclasses besides SleevedShirt that could go inside of the parentheses there.

Let me know what you think.

Also, I'm mostly a beginner, so I wouldn't mind constructive cricitism related to my code if you were willing to offer it.

Comment: How about `article = clothing;`, since `article` is also a type `Clothing`? No cast needed.

Comment: It's that simple? Okay, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the cast to `(SleevedShirt)` as

```
article = clothing;
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the info.